# Scan files on network with Azure Information Protection (do not have 365 yet)

Tags: azure-information-protection

The Azure Information Protection add-in for Office is in maintenance mode, and it is recommended that users use the labels that are built-in to Office 365.

My company has not yet moved all of its employees to 365, so how can we scan folders on our current drives to see what sort of sensitive content/data labels should apply? We are interested in seeing WHAT data we currently have and classifying it before we move to the Cloud.

We attempted to run the Information Protection Scanner starting on 5/15/2023 on an old folder with 24,000 files. It has not run for a week and has not yielded any results yet. I know that the first scan could take some time, but I also read that the scan will not go longer than a week.